# Exchange of limits with an integrable singularity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the following function of the real variable $y$ (it a simplified version of a so-called fidelity in quantum mechanics)

$$F_{N}(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N}\log\left|y-\frac{k}{N}\right|.$$

The mathematical question is: is correct to state that
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{y\to y^*}F_{N}(y)
  \not = \lim_{y\to y^*}\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}F_{N}(y),
$$

for any $y^*\in[0,1]$?

My naive reasoning is this: if we calculate first the limit $y\to y^*$, then increasing $N$ we can find a $x_k=\frac{k}{N}$ arbitrary close to $y^*\in[0,1]$, making the logarithm divergent.

If we instead calculate $N\to \infty$ first, then $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}F_N(y)=-1+(1-y)\log(1-y)+y\log(y)$$ and also the limit $y\rightarrow y^*$ exists.

Thanks a lot.